# Como puedo ocupar getline(); dentro de un struct C++

Tags: c++, struct

buen día.
No logro comprender como puedo usar getline(cin, nombrestring); dentro de una estructura.
es decir si la estructura es competidores y una variable de esa estructura es cmp, al momento de ocupar un ciclo for para pedir datos, utilizo getline(); pero el compilador (DEV C++ que es el que ocupo) me tira el siguiente error.
[Error] no matching function for call to 'getline(std::istream&, char&).
También intenté cmp[i].nombre, pero el compilador me arroja el mismo error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct competidor{
    char nombre;
    char pais[20];
    int numeroMedallas;
    
}cmp[100];

int main (){
    int cant_cmp;
    cout << "Cantidad de competidores: "; cin >> cant_cmp;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < cant_cmp; i++){
        cout << i+1 << endl << "Nombre: ";
        getline(cin, cmp.nombre); //Es mejor que cin.getline?
        while ((cmp.nombre = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF){
            if(cmp.nombre == '\n') break;
        }
    
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) se usa con variables de tipo [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), no `char[]` ni `char`.

El cambio lo tenés que hacer en la estructura:

```
struct competidor{
    string nombre;
    string pais;
    int numeroMedallas;
}cmp[100];
```

En la función `main` el `while` no es necesario ya que `getline` se ocupa de hacer eso. El for quedaría así:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cant_cmp; i++){
    cout << i+1 << endl << "Nombre: ";
    getline(cin, cmp.nombre);
}
```

---

Por cierto, como alternativa a `getch()` podes usar [`cin.get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).